# How do I not present the keyboard on the touch event of a UITextField?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

ok, I know that this topic has been addressed several times on here, but in all of the MANY examples I have looked at, I have been unable to find the answer I need. All I have is a `UITextField`, and when I click on it, I need the keyboard to NOT show-up. Instead, I have a `UIPopoverController` that is showing up.

I have implemented this method:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"here");
    return NO;
}
```

Which should make it so the keyboard stays down, but I can't get this method to fire! What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your forgot to make the object this code lives in the delegate for the textField. Did you drag the delegate in Interface Builder or set the line `textField.delegate = self`.

Answer (score 0):

hey use the delegate of textfield field
in .h with and in .m with   textField.delegate=self;